# Is there a possibility to fix CSV comma problem with Python?

Tags: python, csv

I received a csv file with many data in a comma delimited fashion. The data was in the below format:

```
1,Dame,1900212-apple,mangoes,organges,pine,90,12
2,Mathew,1920121-cargo,90,11
```

How to handle this issue in python when we extract data from CSV?
Please provide some links or directions to it.

As of now they propose to fix that problem in excel file before conversion to CSV. In my case, I don't have access to the original excel file.

Expected Result

```
1,Dame,"1900212-apple,mangoes,organges",90,12
2,Mathew,"1920121-cargo",90,11
```

Comment: What package do you use to read the CSV files?

Comment: what is the issue your facing ?

Comment: pd.read_csv(r'filepath') , i am using pandas,   i hope you find this now easy . Please let me know what i lack in the question? i see  a down-vote too.Cheers

Comment: Let me make it clear again, If i have the original excel file, i can fix this problem by adding double quotes to sentences seperated with comma. If its already in CSV , i cant d o with data. example you can see above question!

Comment: @Gabriel It would be easier to help you if you specify what issue you are facing. At least try mentioning what exactly you want the output to be like to get a better understanding.

Comment: @satilog sure, thanks a lot! i have fixed it. ill try to improve my questions from the very next time

Comment: Should pine be included in the quotes of the first line?

Comment: Pine Not needed to be included, i have also removed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Assumptions:**

- Rows with 5 values per line are clean.
- First two and last two values are not included in the list of items to be merged.

Taking the assumptions above into account, the code reads the csv file line by line and checks if the number of values match 5(which is assumed to be a clean record in the csv) and if it doesnt it merges all values not being the first two values or last two values.

```
from csv import reader

with open('path_to_csv.csv', 'r') as read_obj:
    csv_reader = reader(read_obj)

    for row in csv_reader:
        if len(row) > 5:
            temp = ",".join(row[2:len(row)-2])
            new_row = [*row[0:2],temp,*row[-2:]]
            row = new_row
        print(row)
```

The output is as below,

```
['1', 'Dame', '1900212-apple,mangoes,organges,pine', '90', '12']
['2', 'Mathew', '1920121-cargo', '90', '11']
```

Answer (score 1):

To fix an issue like this, you would need to know some specifics about the file.  For your example, if there are always supposed to be five columns, and only the third column can contain commas, you can merge rows with more than five columns with:

input.csv:

```
1,Dame,1900212-apple,mangoes,organges,pine,90,12
2,Mathew,1920121-cargo,90,11
```

code:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv',newline='') as fin, open('output.csv','w',newline='') as fout:
    reader = csv.reader(fin)
    writer = csv.writer(fout)
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) > 5:
            row[2:-2] = [','.join(row[2:-2])]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

output.csv:

```
1,Dame,"1900212-apple,mangoes,organges,pine",90,12
2,Mathew,1920121-cargo,90,11
```

Note: Be sure to use `newline=''` parameter when opening files for use with the `csv` module as [documented](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.reader) or Excel may read the resulting file incorrectly.